# .htacess não funciona no servidor

Tags: php, htaccess

Olá, quando testo no meu pc, ele funciona perfeitamente, porem quando coloco no servidor ele para de funcionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**.htacess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

**Config**

```
AllowOverride All
```

Obs: quando eu dou include em alguma pagina na index ela carrega normalmente.

Comment: Você chegou a instalar ele? O seu ambiente é Linux ou Windows? Se for Linux de uma lida nesse tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite, se for Windows eu recomendo você a usar ferramentas como Xamp ou Wamp, eu acho que no IIS só o url_rewrite funciona.

Comment: por acaso o rewrite_module está activado?